# Wrong Value is passed as parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, procedure

I face the problem that the parameter value seems not to be taken into account when script is running. What I don't understand is that `Debug.Print()` method shows the right value but the stored procedure in the Access db is not selecting by the value but gives back the result of the SELECT Statement without any limitation referring to the passed parameter value. What is wrong ?

The script is supposed to fill a datagridview of a Winforms application.

```
private void pbSearchDepartment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(OleDbCommand comDeptTotals=conAcc.CreateCommand())
    {       
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        comDeptTotals.CommandText = "sp_ShowDepartmentTotals";
        comDeptTotals.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        Debug.Print(cbDepartments.SelectedItem.ToString());

        comDeptTotals.Parameters.AddWithValue("Area", cbDepartments.SelectedItem);

        conAcc.Open();

        da.SelectCommand = comDeptTotals;
        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.Fill(dt);

        Debug.Print(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

        dgv_NAV_TOTALS.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

The definition of the stored procedure is:

```
PARAMETERS Area Text ( 255 );
SELECT ... FROM... GROUP BY ... HAVING (CC_AREA_MAPPING.Area)=[Area]);
```

I think the @ in front of parameter name doesn't had an effect.
I changed the SP to:

```
PARAMETERS @Area Text ( 255 );
SELECT ... FROM... GROUP BY ... HAVING (CC_AREA_MAPPING.Area)=@Area);
```

Comment: What is the definition of the stored procedure signature?

Comment: Normally the parameters of a stored procedure are starting with an at sign, so `@Area` should be the name of the parameter.

Comment: Why are you first **executing** your query without getting back any data (`da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`), and then you're also filling the dataset using `da.Fill(dt)` !?!? This is totally unnecessary and potentially the cause of the problem - remove the call to `.ExecuteNonQuery()` - that's pointless here (`ExecuteonQuery` is for  `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations - but **not** for `SELECT`....)

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery() is actually not necessary and it "worked" without it. But this has unfortunately not yet solved the problem. The query itself works in Access and the selcteditem is properly recognized by not handed over as parameter as it looks like

Answer (score 2):

thanks for your help. The matter is solved. It is embarrassing for me but to avoid questions what was wrong in the code I can inform you that the code itself is working fine but I used the wrong SP :-\  . Sorry for that.